# Adjusting line-height after larger first-letter

Tags: css

I have a legend for a fieldset where I would like to set the first letter to be very large.  This has the effect of increasing the line-height of the legend and lowering its position relative to the fieldset border.  I would like to be able to raise the vertical alignment of the legend so that the majority of the text is once again middle aligned with the fieldset border.

If I set the line-height of the first letter to zero, it does improve the situation; however, the line-height of the remaining text is still larger than it would be without the large first letter and the vertical alignment isn't quite right.

HTML

```
<fieldset id="fs1">
  <legend>1. Title</legend>
  Some text inside.
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="fs2">
  <legend>1. Title</legend>
  Some text inside.
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="fs3">
  <legend>1. Title</legend>
  Some text inside.
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
fieldset {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

legend {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#fs2 legend:first-letter {
  font-size: 5em;
}

#fs3 legend:first-letter {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

You can see what I mean [here](http://codepen.io/MerceanCoconut/pen/zHwFv)

Comment: Code goes in the question please.

Comment: would this be your answer ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bvleq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by setting the height of the `legend` to 1em and adjusting the vertical positioning a bit.

```
#fs3 legend {
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: -.75em;
}
```

[Codepen fork here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwhAq)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's another solution:

```
#fs3 legend {
  padding-bottom: 43px;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```